# Find the time usage of my app using python

Tags: python, monitor

I have made a python code that runs an application. I need to monitor when the app is opened and running, so that, I will make a graph of usage of my app!!!
Please tell me if you know how.. 
**It's great if I got the piece code directly**
THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can see how to use the python logging feature [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file)

It has very simple examples that you can use to implement the file based logging that you are looking for.